# How could I use purrr's map with a user defined function with variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

How could I use a user defnied funtion with flexible variables in purrr's map?

```
user_fun <- function(data = data, filter_col = "test") {
  data %<%
    select(filter_col)
}
```

How could I use the function in map if I want to change the variable filter_col to "test_22" ?
Thank You

Comment: Do you mean `map(..., user_fun, filter_col = "test2")`?

Comment: thank you VERY MUCH stefan...this was exactely what I am searching for.